# Copy Listview Cell

Tags: vb.net, listview, copy

Is it possible to copy a selected listview cell? I know it's possible to do that in a datagridview but I'm not sure if we can in a listview... For Example:

[image: Copy red rectangle]

```
Dim s As String = ""

For Each lsvrow As ListViewItem In lwBills.SelectedItems
    s &= lsvrow.Text & ControlChars.NewLine
Next

Clipboard.SetDataObject(s)
```

This will copy the row's text (**10133** in this example). The subitems include **206-0015-04B** and **K-3390** but my current example will not copy the subitems. I'm not looking to copy the whole row though, only the part where I have right clicked (in this case **206-0015-04B**)

Can a Listview do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a combination of the `MouseClick` event and the `HitTest` method of the `ListView`.

Handle the `MouseClick` event, and then during the event handler use the `HitTest` method to see which `SubItem` is under the mouse pointer, as follows:

```
Private Sub lwBills_Click(sender As System.Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lwBills.MouseClick
    Dim Info As ListViewHitTestInfo
    Dim s As String

    Info = lwBills.HitTest(e.Location)
    s = Info.SubItem.Text
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(s)
End Sub
```

I am assuming that `lwBills` is the name of your ListView in the above example.